# ASP .NET Core DI: Provide async BaseAddress to HTTP client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

Whenever a client makes a request to my ASP .NET Core 3.1 API, I want to use a `HttpClient` to do some actions in other services.

I registered HttpClient with Dependency Injection:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<MyHttp>();
```

Unfortunately the `BaseAddress`of this `HttpClient` is not static. Instead the client sends a custom header including a reference to a database-entry.
So in order to determine the `BaseAddress` for my HttpClient i need to make an async call to my Database.

Currently I do something like the following:

```cs
public class SomeController
{
    public SomeController(MyHttp http, AddressRepository db)
    {
        _http = http;
        _db = db;
    }
    public async Task<dynamic> SomeAction([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        var address = await _db.Get(id);
        _http.BaseAddress = new Uri(address);
        var res = await _http.GetAsync("some-path");
        //Handle response and do some business-logic
        return new { };
    }
}
```

This works, but whenever i use `MyHttp` in any service I need to make sure that this services sets the `BaseAddress` property.
I'd rather provide the Address as a constructor parameter.
First i thought of a factory implementation. But `services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => {})` does not support async operations (And I understand that object initialization should be fast and reliable).

But I feel like my current solution is also a bad practice. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: You might be able to Add a delegating handler and add your logic in the Send method which is async. There's additional extension methods for adding a handler on top of your AddHttpClient call. Tho not sure how that would work with base address

Answer (score 2):

That is right that service collection registration does not support async factory - because service resolving should be always fast.

But there is nothing wrong with initializing `baseAddress` after client creation. So if your wanna make sure that `httpClient` is initialized with correct base address how about extracting that logic into separate class that will build your http client configuration?

```
public YourHttpClientFactory {
    private IHttpClientFactory _factory;

    public YourHttpClientFactory(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public Task<HttpClient> Create(Guid id) {
        var client = factory.createClient();
        // do your async client initialization
        return client;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But with such a solution I'm not able to imagine how to implement this with Dependency Injection. Because in one Scope (A User request) there will be multiple Services consuming this context (One specific baseAddress for this Scope). If all of those Services use `HttpFactory.Create()` i will have many instances.

Comment: Am I right saying that all your services in the request scope should use the same `baseAddress`? If so you can perform your `baseAddress` intialization in the custom middleware, e.g. register a named http client, resolve it in middleware and perform intiallization based on request info, all your services later in the pipeline will use preconfigured httpclient.